# In Sencha, which persist is better option to save local logins

Tags: sencha-touch-2, data-storage

I am new to Sencha. Hence would like to get advice on:

1. which persistence option is good to have and implement for saving login details in device locally.-Localstorage, SQlite, json, xml?
2. I ran a tutorial, but could not retain the local store proxy data. Probably, data not getting saved in local store. Upon refreshing, I am getting the old getcount only.

Note: I am using Sencha Touch 2.2.1

Please guide me on how to go ahead, and on what I am missing.

Comment: Get good with your developer console, under 'Resources -> Local Storage' you can see exactly what your browser is storing. Takes the guess work out of whether or not your information is being persisted...that is if you are using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1)

I am using the following approach in an application of mine without any problems: I wrapped my Sencha application in a Phonegap project, then made use of the [Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) to save user data in a simple table.

On application start I check if user data are there, if not I do login and save results to storage with a simple `INSERT INTO LOGIN ...`, else start application.
On logout I `TRUNCATE LOGIN`.

The advantage of doing this is that Phonegap gives you a SQLite API, masking what is actually below on each platform. If SQLite is available (i.e. Android?) it will make use of that, else it will fallback on Localstorage (or whatever) without you having to worry about.

Question 2)

Please open another question, giving more details and showing us some code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could do it in local store. And i started storing other data too in local store. but i am observing its taking some loading time. I would go by your suggestion to have Phonegap wrapper and use SQLite. pls suggest me a worth tutorial for wrapping sencha with phone gap. thaks for the encouragement to venture into sencha.

Comment: Follow the tutorial relevant to the platform of your choice http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides. I don't know what you mean with "it's taking some loading time", it depends on what you are actually doing. A small amount of time to retrieve data from filesystem is unavoidable, and you will have it even with Phonagap, but it shouldn't be noticeable for most applications. Also, I see you didn't accept yet any answers, please take a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716.